# edit record with ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I wanted to make a edit record.but I can not change my value has.

```
/models/activite.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
 nomActivite : DS.attr(),
 nb : DS.attr(), 
});
```

my function

```
edit(){
  var controller=this.get('controller');
  console.log(this.store.query('activite',{nomActivite:"work"}));
  this.store.query('activite',{nomActivite:controller.get('nomAct')}).then(function (record) {
      record.set('nb',controller.get('nb'));
      record.save();
      console.log(record.get('nb'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.save()` returns a promise](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_save) so it may be the case that your value hasn't been sent to the backend server by the time you are hitting `console.log()`.

Instead, use the success callback:

```
record.save().then(function(activite){
    console.log(activite.get('nb'));
})
```

Comment: I'm doing this and I have added:                                                                     record.save().then(function(activite){
            console.log(activite.get('nb'));
            console.log(activite.get('nomActivite'));
        });                                                                                                          and return me the value of nb but no nomActivite.but there was no change in the db.thank you for helping me ;)

Comment: I also am a: console.log(record.get('nomActivite')); referring indefinite me, so what is wrong is  this.store.query('activite',{nomActivite:controller.get('nomAct')}) but I do not see what else...